# SQLite: update a record if exists, otherwise insert it?

Tags: sqlite

I tried `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO`, but it doesn't preserve the row id when it replaces the record to update it. Another option is do it in two steps: `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO` then `UPDATE`, but I would prefer a one step solution. So I am wondering if SQLite has something like the `MERGE` keyword or other simple solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SQLite doesn't support `MERGE` or upsert.

You can use your two-step solution, but what you probably really want is for the `ROWID` to be a first-class column in your table.  If you declare a column as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, it will be an alias for the `ROWID`.  Then `INSERT OR REPLACE` will work fine.